# Qual a diferença entre "&&" e "||" e "and" e "or" em PHP? Qual usar?

Tags: php, operadores

Tenho essa dúvida, qual a diferença entre `&&` e `||` e entre `and` e `or`? Qual deles devo usar?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A diferença entre eles está na ordem de precedência de cada um.

## Ordem de precedência? Mas o quê?!

Por exemplo, tomemos a expressão matemática **3+4*2**. Qual o resultado da expressão? 14 ou 11? A resposta é **11**, pois o operador `*` tem uma precedência maior que o operador `+`.

Nesse caso de `&&`, `||`, *`and`* e *`or`*, os dois primeiros têm precedência maior sobre os outros dois, caso contrário, são idênticos.

Em PHP também existem os operadores `&` e `|`, mas esses fazem comparações *bit-a-bit* e entre referências, ao invés dos outros citados, que fazem operações lógicas propriamente ditas.

Comment: +1 pela explicação da precedência. Já ouvi usuários que usam `OR`ao invés de `||` só porque é mais bonito.

Comment: Apenas acrescentando: Ao fazer o seguinte exemplo, nota-se uma pequena diferença entre os resultados: `var_dump(1 or 2)` é diferente de `var_dump(1 || 2)`. O primeiro retorna `int(1)` e o segundo retorna `bool(true)`

Comment: Usar `OR` e `AND` também facilita a leitura do código para leigos. Mas essa diferença de resultados eu não sabia, primeiro porque não sei nada de PHP. Hehe

Comment: @WallaceMaxters: ao menos no PHP 5.4, `var_dump(1 or 2)` imprime `bool(true)`. Uma pena que esse recurso, tão útil e usado no Python por exemplo, não funcione no PHP

Answer (score 23):

Essa imagem ilustra bem a diferença entre ambos os [**operadores lógicos**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.logical.php).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ambos os operadores resultam como resultado um valor booleano ou seja, verdadeiro(*true*) ou falso(*false*).

**And**: `$a and $b`: Retorna verdadeiro se ambos os valores passados são verdadeiros.

**Or**: `$a and $b`: Retorna verdadeiro se `$a` ou `$b` são verdadeiros.

**Xor**: `$a xor $b`: Embora você não tenha citado esse operador, é semelhante ao `Or`, retorna verdadeiro se `$a` ou `$b` são verdadeiros **mas não ambos**.

**!**: `! $a`: Operador unário, retorna verdadeiro se `$a` **não é** verdadeiro.

**&&**: `$a && $b`: Operador binário, retorna verdadeiro se tanto `$a` quanto `$b` forem verdadeiros.

**||**: `$a || $b`: Operador binário, retorna verdadeiro se `$a` **ou** `$b` são verdadeiros.

### Precedência de Operadores

Assim como foi explicado na [**resposta do mutley**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47892/6454), a diferença entre esses operadores está na precedência entre eles, ou seja qual o operador é avaliado primeiro e qual será o avaliado em seguida, como você pode ver na tabela a seguir, tanto `&&` como `||` têm prioridade sobre `And` e `Or`.

A tabela seguinte mostra a precedência dos operadores, da maior precedência no começo para os de menor precedência.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Exemplo

```
// AND
var_dump(  7 == 7  AND 9 > 7  );  // TRUE, ambas as expressões são verdadeiras
var_dump(  7 == 7  AND 9 < 7  );  // FALSE, apenas a primeira expressão é verdadeira

// OR
var_dump(  7 == 7  OR 9 > 7  );   // TRUE, ambas as expressões são verdadeiras
var_dump(  7 != 7  OR 9 > 7  );   // TRUE, a segunda expressão é verdadeira
var_dump(  7 != 7  OR 9 < 7  );   // FALSE, ambas as expressões são falsas

// XOR
var_dump(  7 == 7  XOR 9 > 7  );  // FALSE, ambas as expressões são verdadeiras
var_dump(  7 == 7  XOR 9 < 7  );  // TRUE, a primeira expressão é verdadeira
var_dump(  7 < 7  XOR 9 > 7  );   // TRUE, a segunda expressão é verdadeira

// !
var_dump(  ! 9 < 7  );   // TRUE, 9 NÃO é menor que 7
var_dump(  ! 9 > 7  );   // FALSE, 9 é maior que 7

// &&
var_dump(  7 == 7  && 9 > 7  );   // TRUE, ambas as expressões são verdadeiras
var_dump(  7 == 7  && 9 < 7  );   // FALSE, apenas a primeira expressão é verdadeira

// ||
var_dump(  7 == 7  || 9 > 7  );   // TRUE, ambas as expressões são verdadeiras
var_dump(  7 != 7  || 9 > 7  );   // TRUE, a segunda expressão é verdadeira
var_dump(  7 != 7  || 9 < 7  );   // FALSE, ambas as expressões são falsas
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/smIw4r)</kbd>

Referência: [Operadores de comparação, operadores lógicos e a precedência dos operadores no PHP](http://aprenderphp.com.br/artigo/operadores-de-comparacao-operadores-logicos-e-a-precedencia-dos-operadores-no-php/)

Comment: +1 pelas tabelas

Answer (score 8):

Este são [operadores lógicos](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) resultam sempre um valor do tipo booleano (`true` ou `false`) e são muito usados onde se espera uma expressão condicional.

`&&` resulta em `true` se os dois operandos dele forem verdadeiros, por isto é comum que estes operandos sejam [relacionais](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

`||` reulta em `true` se pelo menos um dos dois operandos sejam verdadeiros.

`and` e `or` são os equivalentes aos operadores anteriores mas tem um [precedência](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) menor.

Conforme a documentação mostra no primeiro caso a interpretação é esta:

```
($e = (false || true))
```

Já no segundo caso fica assim:

```
(($f = false) or true)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/TwoOr.php).

Portanto no primeiro caso a expressão condicional usando o operador `||` é mais importante e executa primeiro. No segundo caso o segundo operando funciona como algo adicional, o importante é a expressão de atribuição anterior. Este exemplo não faz nada útil, porque sempre funcionará o `$f = false` e o `true` nunca será executado.

Aí vem uma curiosidade que nem todos sabem. Estes operadores funcionam em forma de curto-circuito, ou seja, se ele já pode antecipar o resultado final ele não continua executando. No caso do `or` se a primeira expressão já é considerada verdadeira, a segunda não precisa ser mais executada, com um `or` basta uma das duas expressões serem verdadeiras. Com o `and` o ocorre o oposto, se a primeira expressão for falsa, a segunda não precisa ser executada já que é impossível que o resultado final seja verdadeiro, lembrando que um `and` exige que ambas expressões devem ser verdadeiras para resultar em verdadeiro.

Comment: Acho que essa resposta foi a unica que abordou do funcionamento "curto circuito" dos operadores

if (existe() and Insert()) .. isso é muito usando no java para verificar se o objeto é uma instancia de X para somente depois chamar um método, tudo dentro de um único if
+1

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes: a lógica está correta, mas seu exemplo confunde: no caso de um hipotético `existe()` e `insert()`, usaríamos o **OR**, e não **AND**: apenas insere caso não exista.

Answer (score 4):

Os operadores `&&` e `||` tem precedência maior sobre `and` e `or`. Isso determina a ordem em que eles serão executados. `&&` e `||` são executados antes de `and` e `or`.

[Link do Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)