# Interpretador de Textos em PHP

Tags: php

Estou criando um interpretador de texto com base na documentação do [Github do DuckDuckGo](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-goodies/tree/master/lib/DDG/Goodie) em PHP.

Esse é um dos códigos que criei:

```
if (strpos(strtolower($qt), "rand") !== FALSE){
  if (preg_match("/^rand$/", strtolower(removeAccents($qt)), $match)){
    $result = rand(1,9999);
    $sndline = "Random number";
  }
  elseif (preg_match("/^random$/", strtolower(removeAccents($qt)), $match)){
    $result = rand(1,9999);
    $sndline = "Random number";
  }
  elseif (preg_match("/^rand *\((?<min>[0-9]+),(?<max>[0-9]+)\)$/", strtolower(removeAccents($qt)), $match)){
    $result = rand($match['min'],$match['max']);
    $sndline = "Random number";
  }
  elseif (preg_match("/^random *\((?<min>[0-9]+),(?<max>[0-9]+)\)$/", strtolower(removeAccents($qt)), $match)){
    $result = rand($match['min'],$match['max']);
    $sndline = "Random number";
  }
}
```

Como vocês podem ver, o script realiza a ação se o usuário digitar `rand`, `random`, `rand (1,99)` e `random (1,99)`.

Todo o interpretador foi escrito com funções `preg_match` (ou seja, tudo com RegEx) mas descobri que elas sobrecarregam o sistema.

Como posso criar algo que seja rápido (sem sobrecarregar o sistema) e que entenda também diferentes "ordens" dadas pelo usuário sem usar RegEx (lembrando que o usuário pode digitar qualquer coisa na pesquisa)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu vejo pelo menos três pontos que podem ser otimizados com facilidade:

1. O `if` mais de fora parece desnecessário.
2. O `strtolower(removeAccents($qt))` pode acabar sendo executado mais de uma vez (4 vezes se você digitar `random (1,99)`).
3. Os dois primeiros casos são uma comparação de igualdade, e você não precisa usar regex para isso.

Traduzindo isso em código:

```
$cleanQt = strtolower(removeAccents($qt));
if ($cleanQt == "rand"){
  $result = rand(1,9999);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
elseif ($cleanQt == "random"){
  $result = rand(1,9999);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
elseif (preg_match("/^rand *\((?<min>[0-9]+),(?<max>[0-9]+)\)$/", $cleanQt), $match)){
  $result = rand($match['min'],$match['max']);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
elseif (preg_match("/^random *\((?<min>[0-9]+),(?<max>[0-9]+)\)$/", $cleanQt, $match)){
  $result = rand($match['min'],$match['max']);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
```

E acho que ainda dá pra condensar os dois últimos testes em um só:

```
$cleanQt = strtolower(removeAccents($qt));
if ($cleanQt == "rand"){
  $result = rand(1,9999);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
elseif ($cleanQt == "random"){
  $result = rand(1,9999);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
elseif (preg_match("/^rand|random *\((?<min>[0-9]+),(?<max>[0-9]+)\)$/", $cleanQt), $match)){
  $result = rand($match['min'],$match['max']);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
```

E ainda, como mostra o qmechanik, dá pra fundir as duas primeiras condições:

```
$cleanQt = strtolower(removeAccents($qt));
if ($cleanQt == "rand" || $cleanQt == "random"){
  $result = rand(1,9999);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
elseif (preg_match("/^rand|random *\((?<min>[0-9]+),(?<max>[0-9]+)\)$/", $cleanQt), $match)){
  $result = rand($match['min'],$match['max']);
  $sndline = "Random number";
}
```

Comment: Vamos supor que eu tenha mais do que um desses "módulos", vou ter que adicionar mais condições (elseif)?

Comment: É um caminho. Mas dependendo da complexidade das suas regras, vale a pena estudar um pouco sobre *lexers* e *parsers* e implementar algo mais genérico.

Comment: Complexidade você diz em que sentido?

Comment: Por exemplo, se você tem muitas dessas palavras-chaves para serem identificadas nos dados de entrada, se elas podem aparecer em diferentes posições, se podem se agrupar em expressões, se a ordem faz diferença, entre outros aspectos. Quanto mais as suas regras se aproximarem de uma "linguagem", mais adequado fica representá-la em [BNF](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalismo_de_Backus-Naur) e criar um parser para ela.

Comment: Sem ir na direção de _lexers_ e _parsers_, tem outra maneira de ir adicionando novos módulos sem ter que criar novos elseifs?

Comment: Não, é na base das condicionais com `if`, `elseif` e `else` mesmo. Em certos casos de comparação de igualdade da string com uma lista de termos você pode optar por um `switch` e reagir de acordo, mas não faz muita diferença.

Comment: Se eu adicionar muitos `elseif`, o código ainda ficará rápido?

Comment: Depende do que você fizer nele, não existe resposta absoluta.

Comment: Um caminho geral (que os lexers constumam tomar) é pegar a string inteira, quebrar numa lista de "palavras" (*tokens*) e varrer essa lista comparando os termos com o que você aceita, interpretando linearmente a "frase" inteira.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não tenho competência nem tempo pra detalhar isso agora. Mas quem sabe algum colega aqui do site não posta uma resposta nesse sentido mais tarde.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23824/discussion-between-hsbpedro-and-bfavaretto).

Comment: @hsbpedro Desculpe, mas agora não vai dar pra falar no chat, estou encerrando o dia. Mas vai tentando pequenas mudanças e testando a diferença de performance.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento e pela ajuda!

Answer (score 4):

Conforme [mencionado pelo bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64274/6454), o primeiro `if` é desnecessário, pois logo abaixo há outro `if` que faz *praticamente* a mesma coisa, com exceção que este último usa a função `removeAccents`.

1. Você poderia economizar algumas linhas por declarar uma vez somente a variável `sndline`, fora do bloco de código do `if`.
2. Os blocos de código dos dois primeiros `if` são iguais, assim como os dois últimos também são, utilize o [operador lógico `or`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.logical.php) para fazer a verificação na mesma linha.

   <sub>**Nota**: Você também pode usar o operador `||`, mais informações em [**Qual a diferença entre “&&” e “||” e “and” e “or” em PHP? Qual usar?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/6454)</sub>
3. O uso da função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) nos dois primeiros `if` pode ser substituído pelo [operador de igualdade `==`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php) (`===` para algo mais rígido) ou [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcmp.php), [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcasecmp.php).
4. Um outro ponto que pode ser melhorarado, é declarar uma variável que contenha o valor de `strtolower(removeAccents($qt))`, deste modo você evita executar essas *funções* várias vezes, sem necessidade.
5. Você usa a função `preg_match` nos dois últimos `if` para verificar se a variável `qt` contém a palavra *rand* ou *random* seguido por números, você pode substituí-la pela função [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php), usada para filtrar o conteúdo de uma *string*, como você quer somente números, use como filtro `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`.

   - Combine a função [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) com [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php) para encontrar números que tenham como prefixo a palavra *rand* ou *random*.

O teu código com essas sugestões ficaria assim:

```php
function filtrarNumeros($texto){
    return filter_var($texto, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
$qt = strtolower(removeAccents($qt));
$sndline = "Random number";

if (($qt == "rand") or ($qt == "random")){
    $result = rand(1, 9999);
}
elseif (filtrarNumeros((strstr($qt, 'rand')) !== false) or (filtrarNumeros(strstr($qt, 'random')) !== false)){
    $tok = strtok($qt, ",");
    $min = filtrarNumeros($tok);
    $max = filtrarNumeros(strtok(','));
    $result = rand($min, $max);
}
else{
    // ....
}
```

[**`Exemplo`**](http://ideone.com/SolW67)

Comment: Legal, com direito a `strtok` ;)