# Qual a melhor forma de utilizar operadores lógicos diferentes em uma mesma condição?

Tags: php, operadores

Preciso **utilizar dois operadores lógicos diferentes** em **uma mesma condição**. Como fazer de forma correta?

Eu fiz desse jeito:

```
if($planohabilitargestao!="1000" || $planohabilitargestao!="200" || $planohabilitargestao!="10000" && $usuario=="")
```

Mesmo a variável `$planohabilitargestao` sendo igual de 1000, 200 e 10000 a condição é executada.

Tem separar os **operadores iguais** com parênteses?

Comment: Só com estas informações não dá para responder. Diga o que deseja fazer.

Comment: @bigown a condição acima está correta? gostaria de saber se tenho que separar os operadores iguais com parenteses.

Comment: Qual é resultado esperado e qual é o resultado obtido? parece que o seu teste falha em validar o esperado ...

Comment: @rray Mesmo a variável $planohabilitargestao sendo igual de 1000, 200 e 10000 a condição é executada.

Comment: Explique para que ser esse código, `$planohabilitargestao` sendo 200, é diferente de 1000 logo da `true`, ficou mais confunso agora O.o'

Comment: o que você tem na variável $usuario

Comment: A pergunta está clara, a sugestão dada (de usar parênteses) por ele está errada, mas a resposta é obvia. É claro que é executa. Porque você define 1000, a variável é ativada pelo !=200 "e" pelo !=10000. Você deve usar `AND` ou `&&`, que é mesma coisa. Daí sim. Se ele for diferente de 1000 E diferente de 200 E diferente de 10000 ele será executada. Então se você usar 1000 ele não vai executar.

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini 
A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e ajudar a todos entender isso. Também pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Os operadores possuem precedência igual na matemática, e o operador `&&` que é um `AND` tem mais precedência que o operador `||` que é um `OR`. Ambos possuem associatividade da esquerda para direita, então quando os operadores tem a mesma precedência, será executado primeiro a sub-expressão que aparece primeiro.

Neste exemplo há um `&&`, portando esta sub-expressão será executada antes de tudo de acordo com a precedência de operadores, então `$planohabilitargestao != "10000" && $usuario == ""` é a primeira operação a ser executada para depois relacionar com os demais `||`. Entendo que isto não é o que deseja.

A solução para isto é usar parenteses mudando a precedência, já que o este operador `()` tem precedência mais alta que os demais. Basta fazer isto:

```
($planohabilitargestao != "1000" || $planohabilitargestao != "200" || $planohabilitargestao != "10000) && $usuario == ""
```

Agora a expressão do `&&` tem como primeiro operado o resultado final da expressão que está entre parênteses, então todos os operadores `||` são executado primeiro para depois o resultado ser usado como operando de `&&`.

Por outro lado pode ser (depois da edição) que só queira isto:

```
$planohabilitargestao != "1000" && $planohabilitargestao != "200" && $planohabilitargestao != "10000 && $usuario == ""
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/Logical.php).

Pelo menos é o que eu "adivinhei" que desejava, espero ter acertado. Ainda tento outras opções se o problema for melhor definido.

[Tabela de precedência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/101).

Comment: Deu certo não... Mesmo a variável $planohabilitargestao sendo igual de 1000, 200 e 10000 a condição é executada.

Comment: O problema é que você não sabe o que você deseja. Se você definir melhor, eu tento melhorar. De fato eu acho isto esquisito, mas a definição do problema é que está errado. É sintomático que o código foi mudado na pergunta original. lembrando que uma variável não pode ser igual a vários valores.

Comment: @bigown Acho que o problema dela esta na variável $usuario tem que ver o que esta esta passando.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza é uma possibilidade sim.