# Problemas com PDO do PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Seguinte, tenho o seguinte método em uma classe chamada `UsuarioDAO`.

```
 public function insertUser(PojoUser $user) {

    if ($stmt = Conn::con() != null) {

        $stmt = Conn::con()->prepare('INSERT INTO usuario (email, username, password, lastaccess, active, createdat, updatedat) VALUES (:email, :username, :password, :lastaccess, :active, :createdat, :udatedat)');

        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $user->getEmail(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":username", $user->getUsername(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":password", $user->getPassword(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":lastaccess", $user->getLastAccess(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":active", $user->getActive(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(":createdat", $user->getCreatedAt(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":udatedat", $user->getUpdatedAt(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();

    } else {
        echo "<p class='msg-error'> Desculpe! Erro ao estabelecer conexão. Tente novamente mais tarde.</p>";
    }
}
```

Essa classe recebe como parâmetro um objeto do `PojoUser`, segue o código da classe abaixo:

```
<?php

class PojoUser {

    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $lastAccess;
    private $active;
    private $createdAt;
    private $updatedAt;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($senha) {
        $this->senha = $senha;
    }    

    public function getLastAccess() {
        return $this->lastAccess;
    }

    public function setLastAccess($lastAccess) {
        $this->lastAccess = $lastAccess;
    }

    public function getActive() {
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function setActive($active) {
        $this->active = $active;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt) {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt) {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }

}

?>
```

Eu chamo essas duas classes na página de registro de usuário:

```
<?php

include_once('Register.class.php');
include_once('UserDao.class.php');
include_once('PojoUser.class.php');
if ($_POST) {

    $email = $_POST['user-email'];
    $password = $_POST['user-password'];
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $conUserPassword = $_POST['conf-user-password'];

    /*$re = new Register();*/

    $user = new PojoUser();
    $userDAO = new UserDAO();
    $data = date('d/m/Y');


    if ($password == $conUserPassword) {

        if (!($userDAO->userExists($email))) {

            if ($userDAO->userNameAvaiable($username)) {

                $cryptoPassword = $userDAO->crypto($password);

                $user->setEmail($email);
                $user->setUsername($username);
                $user->setPassword($cryptoPassword);
                $user->setLastAccess($data);
                $user->setActive(0);
                $user->setCreatedAt($data);
                $user->setUpdatedAt($data);

                $userDAO->insertUser($user);



                //echo "<p class='msg-success'>Usuário Cadastrado com sucesso! Confirme seu email por favor.</p>";

            } else {
                echo "<p class='msg-error'>Desculpe, este nome de usuário não está mais disponível</p>";
            }

        } else {
            echo "<p class='msg-error'>Hey, parece que você já esteve por aqui, este email já está cadastrado em nosso sistema!</p>";
        }

    } else {

        echo "<p class='msg-error'>Verifique se você digitou as senhas corretamente!</p>";
    }

}

?>
```

Meu problema, é que o usuário nunca é registrado no banco. Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o porquê disso?

Comment: Algum erro é exibido?

Comment: Não, nenhum erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, o erro estava no setter de password da minha classe `PojoUser`:

```
private $id;
private $email;
private $username;
private $password;
private $lastAccess;
private $active;
private $createdAt;
private $updatedAt;

public function setPassword($senha) {
    $this->password = $senha;
}  

public function getPassword() {
    return $this->password;
}
```

Eu não estava referenciando a variável `$password` mas sim um variável não existente `$senha`, isso fazia minha senha ir sempre nula para o método de inserção, o que não permitia o cadastro no banco de dados, pois o meu getter retornava `password`.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o erro está nessa linha:

```
if ($stmt = Conn::con() != null) {
```

A expressão acima avalia se `Conn::con()` não é nulo, e o resultado é um valor *booleano* que é atribuído a variável  `$stmt`. Veja um exemplo:

```
$foo = null;

$bar = ($foo != null); // False porque $foo NÃO é diferente de null
$baz = ($foo == null); // True porque $foo é igual a null

var_dump($bar, $baz);
```

A forma correta é primeiro atribuir a `$stmt` o valor de `Conn::con()` e então fazer a comparação:

```
if (($stmt = Conn::con()) != null) {
```

O porquê disto se deve a [precedência dos operadores](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.precedence.php), mais detalhes: [**Qual a diferença entre “&&” e “||” e “and” e “or” em PHP? Qual usar?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/6454)

Comment: Não, não é isso. Fiz essa modificação, e não funcionou do mesmo jeito. Mas quando eu passo um array com todos os getters do objeto, como parâmetro do execute(), funciona. Mas realmente queria entender o pq de não funcionar desse jeito.

Comment: @GaMen Se não é isso, tente o seguinte dentro do `if (...) {` ..: `var_dump($stmt);`.

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=&gt;
  string(120) "INSERT INTO `usuario` (email, username, password, lastaccess, active, createdat, updatedat) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
}

Comment: No que você sugeriu

Comment: @GaMen E na forma que você estava usando não? outra coisa, verifique se os dados estão vindo corretamente, exemplo: `echo $user->getEmail();`.

Comment: Não, na forma que eu estava usando também não funciona. Sim, os dados estão vindo perfeitos, já testei isso.

Comment: @GaMen No `execute` veja o que é retornado: `var_dump($stmt->execute());`, *false* ou *true*.

Comment: E veja também: `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());`, se preferir fazer um `try/catch`..: `try { // código de inserção } catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` também pode mostrar alguma coisa.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Não tinha percebido o erro até você sugerir que eu usasse o var_dump($stmt->execute());. A senha estava indo nula. O erro está no setter de senha na classe PojoUser, eu não referenciei a variável password. Qnd você mandou eu testar os dados, a variável senha foi a única que eu pulei kkkk Mas mto obrigado, e desculpa o incômodo.

Comment: @GaMen Não foi imcomôdo. :) Se quiser postar isso como resposta e aceitá-la, pode ajudar outros com problemas semelhantes.

Comment: Vou fazer isso o/