# Onde esta o erro que eu não consigo ver?

Tags: php, codeigniter, lógica

O que acontece no `jeans_status` and `jeans_opcao` ele funciona uma beleza mais no primeiro `if` não funciona, ele entra no `if` sem verificar se o `imagem_status == 1` e a `imagem_opcao == 'galeria_imagem'`.
Alguém se habilita a me explicar o que ta pegando ?

```
<?php
            //  pd($imagens);
            foreach ($imagens as $value) {
                if (isset($value->imagem_status) == 1 and $value->imagem_opcao == "galeria_imagem") {
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">

                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->imagem_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">

                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>

                <?php } elseif ($value->jeans_status == 1 and $value->jeans_opcao == "galeria_jeans") { ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">



                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/jeans/' . $value->jeans_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->jeans_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/jeans/' . $value->jeans_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->jeans_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->jeans_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">
                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: vc não está verificando se `imagem_status` é igual a `1` vc está verificando se o `isset()` é `1` (true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A atual verificação, compara se o resultado o `isset()` é true e se `imagem_opcao` é `galeria_imagem`. Sugiro também que troque o `and` por `&&` já que eles não são iguais, tem prioridades diferentes.

Mude:

```
isset($value->imagem_status) == 1 and $value->imagem_opcao == "galeria_imagem"
```

Para:

```
isset($value->imagem_status) && $value->imagem_status == 1 && $value->imagem_opcao == "galeria_imagem"
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Qual a diferença entre “&&” e “||” e “and” e “or” em PHP? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/91)

Comment: Perfeito amigo. Mais olha ai, eu não sabia que o isset já entrava na condicional