# Operadores lógicos em validação de formulário com php

Tags: php, html

Bom dia,

Tenho esses campos em um formulário html e estou tentando validá-lo com php.
Na minha validação com o php, eu preciso que apenas um dos campos (qualquer um) seja obrigatório. No caso, o usuário precisa preencher pelo menos um dos campos para que possa ser feito o envio do formulário.

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="oemail" placeholder="Digite seu E-mail">
<input type="tel" name="whats" id="whats" placeholder="Digite seu whatsapp" maxlength="15">
<input type="tel" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="Digite seu telefone" maxlength="14">
```

estou fazendo a validação com o seguinte código. (funcionando)

```
if (empty($whats) OR strstr($whats, ' ')==false) {
    $erro = 1;
}
if ($erro != 0) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "erro.php";</script>';
    exit;
}
```

Tentei usar o seguinte código, mas como os *entendedores* podem ver, não funciona:

```
if (empty($whats) OR strstr($whats, ' ')==false) and (empty($telefone) OR strstr($telefone, ' ')==false) and (empty($email) OR strstr($email, ' ')==false) {
    $erro = 1;
}
if ($erro != 0) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "erro.php";</script>';
    exit;
}
```

As perguntas são as seguintes:

- Para o meu problema, está é a maneira mais correta de validar o
  formulário? Se não, qual seria a melhor?
- Como eu conseguiria montar a lógica da segunda tentativa, corretamente dentro do php?

Comment: Só não entendi a finalidade do `strstr`, o que ele valida? Relacionda: [Qual a diferença entre “&&” e “||” e “and” e “or” em PHP? Qual usar?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/91)

Comment: Peguei esse código da internet, não sei exatamente o que faz. Sou programador apenas front.

Comment: @LeoAmaral `strstr()` está sendo usado pra checar se não existem espaços na string recebida. Se você não precisa dessa validação pode retirar: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php

Answer (score 4):

> preciso que apenas um dos campos (qualquer um) seja obrigatório.

Com base apenas nessa regra, o código abaixo vai funcionar:

```
if ( !empty($whats) || !empty($telefone) || !empty($email) ) {
    // válido, pelo menos um campo não está vazio
} else {
   // inválido
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "erro.php";</script>';
    exit;
}
```

> Para o meu problema, está é a maneira mais correta de validar o
>   formulário? Se não, qual seria a melhor?

**Como validar melhor o formulário:**

A validação acima funciona mas tem algumas coisas que você pode fazer pra deixar sua validação mais segura e útil.

**Conferir o formato do telefone com [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php):**

Se você tem uma máscara validando telefones no front-end pode validar o formato no PHP pra garantir que está recebendo só dados válidos. Exemplo:

```
if ( !preg_match( '|\(\d{2}\)\s\d{4}\d?\-\d{4}|', trim($telefone) ) {
    // telefone inválido pois não está no formato
    // (99) 9999-9999 ou (99) 99999-9999
}
```

**Conferir o formato do email com [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php):**

```
if ( ! filter_var( trim($email), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
   // email inválido
}
```

Note que eu usei [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php) nas variáveis para retirar qualquer espaço no começo ou no final da string. É bom usar pra evitar erros de validação causados por espaços extras.

Comment: Somente para complementar a resposta: seria ideal criar filtros e as mesmas condições também no lado do cliente, via Javascript. Dessa forma quando preencher o campo de telefone, por exemplo, ficaria exatamente da forma desejada.

Answer (score 3):

Outra alternativa é usar a função `array_filter()` ela vai verificar cada item do array, caso seja vazio ele não será devolvido, ou seja se existir pelo menos um valor ele será avaliado como `true` no if.

```
$itens = array($whats, $telefone, $email);
if(array_filter($itens)){
    echo 'algum valor foi preenchido';
}else{
    echo 'nada foi preenchido';
}
```