# Preciso usar "Convert.ToInt32()" para texto?

Tags: c#, .net, estilo-de-codificação, conversão-de-tipo

Penso que seja algo com o `Convert.ToInt32()`, pois eu não entendi sua função dentro da linguagem.

**Observação 1:**
O lugar onde aprendo é norte-americano e não manjo muito de inglês.

**Observação 2:**
Este é o código:

```
using.system;
using.system.Collections.Generic;
using.system.Ling;
using.system.Text;
using.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace T1
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minha primeira sugestão é procurar alguma fonte que seja mais fácil para você. Aconselho procurar entender todos aspectos da programação antes, ou pelo menos junto da linguagem. Aprender linguagem é fácil, aprender programar é bem mais difícil e não costuma funcionar bem quando a pessoa tenta aprender programar junto com a linguagem.

Você quer ler algo do console, ou seja, quer deixar o usuário digitar algo, certo? Então escolheu o método correto. O [`ReadLine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Console_ReadLine) manda ler uma linha no console. Clica aí nela e veja a documentação. Sempre é importante ler toda documentação com bastante atenção antes de usar alguma coisa. Ali diz que o retorno desde método é um valor do tipo [`string`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

O que deseja fazer? Imprimir isso? Ok, não precisa conversão, afinal *strings* são as únicas coisas que realmente você consegue imprimir de forma que o ser humano consegue entender. Mesmo quando manda imprimir um número ele precisa ser convertido para *string* para imprimir. E geralmente essa conversão ocorre automaticamente pelo método de impressão.

Vamos organizar o código e consertar os erros de sintaxe. Organizar ajuda entender o código, e quanto antes perceber essa importância, mais rápido evoluirá. E escrever tudo certo é fundamental para o código compilar, funcionar e estar certo. Ressaltando que funciona é diferente de estar certo. O que você deve buscar sempre é estar certo, mais que funcionar.

```
using System;

namespace T1 { 
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            string x = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8G2lfK). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tsRpAY). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Format1.cs).

- Eu tirei os importadores desnecessários pra este código,
- indentei corretamente,
- coloquei em maiúsculo o que precisa ser (isso conta, `Console` é diferente `console`,
- coloquei `;` onde precisava,
- consertei o `using` que tinha um ponto onde não devia.

Nesse exemplo dá para simplificar ainda mais. Variáveis são locais de armazenamento de valores em memória com um nome para facilitar o entendimento do programador. Você precisa armazenar algum valor nesse exemplo? Não, você precisa de um valor, mas não armazenar. Vou removê-la então.

Em geral em códigos simples não precisam criar um [`namespace`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101). Removê-lo simplifica um pouco mais. *Namespaces* servem para organizar código muito grandes, o que não é o caso.

C# permite fazer interpolação de *strings*, ou seja, pode colocar código dentro das aspas e ele será considerado parte do código e não parte do texto. Isto pode ser uma simplificação.

Você pode importar uma classe estática se quiser, aí o código fica mais curto. Nesse caso o ganho não é grande, mas já pode ir acostumando:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WriteLine($"{ReadLine()}");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rSxVbf). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/chm2NZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Format2.cs).

Quando precisar calcular algo que está em formato texto, é preciso convertê-lo para números. O método [`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads) pode ser usado quando tem certeza que a conversão dará certo. Não é o caso de um dado entrado pelo teclado. O usuário pode digitar algo que não pode ser convertido para número. Neste caso o melhor a fazer é tentar a conversão e só se ela funcionar é que use o valor obtido. Usamos o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) para isto ([veja também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101)).

Vou usar [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15566/101) para fins didáticos, mas não abuse deles em condições normais.

Usarei o [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101) para introduzir um novo conceito para você você. Ele "descobre" o tipo da variável sozinha, se tiver algo que permita o compilador fazer isto. Só não abuse dele.

Não sei se já aprendeu usar o `if`, ele é uma das coisas mais importantes da programação e tem muito programador "experiente" que ainda não sabe usá-lo corretamente, apesar de ser fácil. Ele toma decisões se um bloco de comandos será executado ou não. Ele precisa de um valor booleano, ou seja, precisa ser verdadeiro ou falso. Se não domina isto, faça perguntas específicas.

O método `TryParse()` retorna justamente um booleano indicando se a operação de conversão foi bem sucedida ou não. Se for, ele guarda o valor convertido no [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) de saída (`out`) do método. Como há duas conversão, nós pegamos os dois resultados e aplicações um operador de *and*, ou seja, o resultado final só será verdadeiro se ambos forem verdadeiros ([é outra linguagem, mas funciona igual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/101)).

O armazenamento agora é necessário, por isso criamos variáveis.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var texto1 = ReadLine(); //pede o texto e armazena em variável
        int numero1; //declara a variável que receberá o número1
        var texto2 = ReadLine(); //pede o texto e armazena em variável
        int numero2; //declara a variável que receebrá o número2
        if (int.TryParse(texto1, out numero1) && int.TryParse(texto2, out numero2)) WriteLine($"{texto1} + {texto2} = {numero1 + numero2}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/We55Os). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/27DO3p). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Format3.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais deveria especificar onde ocorre o erro, assim por alto não consigo ver o que está errado com o código, mas é de salientar que o que vem na string **tem que ser um número** (se estiver errado corrijam) pois se não for dará erro. Quando você não tem a certeza o que vem na string (se vem um número ou não) veja o que é e use o **int.TryParse**

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, primeiro de tudo: C# é case sensitive. Ou seja, ele diferencia maiusculas de minusculas. Não sei se foi na hora de passar o seu código para cá mas você está chamando **convert** ao invés de **Convert** e **console** ao invés de **Console**.

Segundo: o método `Convert.ToInt32(string value);` converte um valor passado como parametro para um inteiro de 32 bits. Caso o valor passado não seja um inteiro válido, ele lançará uma exceção (FormatException).

Terceiro (o que acredito ser o seu problema): como eu disse, o retorno deste método é um **inteiro**. Perceba que sua variavel x é do tipo **string**. Uma **string** não pode receber um **inteiro** diretamente.
Ou você muda o tipo da variavel x para `int`, ou você usa um `.ToString()` para efetuar a conversão.

ficando:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

ou

```
string x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()).ToString();
```

É bem aceitavel e até elegante declarar sua variavel com `var`.
Dessa forma você instrui o compilador a deduzir o tipo que será recebido pela variavel.

```
var x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Lembrando que, como não há validação do que o usuario insere no console, pode ser lançada uma exception caso o mesmo insira um valor não válido (uma letra por exemplo).