# O que significa dizer que uma expressão sofre curto circuito?

Tags: php, operadores

Na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.logical.php) do PHP, sobre operadores diz:

> // foo() nunca será chamada porque toda a **expressão sofre curto circuito**.

O que significa dizer que toda toda a expressão sofre curto circuito? O que acontece com o *script* em tempo de execução?

```
<?php

// --------------------
// foo() nunca será chamada porque toda a expressão sofre curto circuito

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

Comment: [Qual a diferença entre “&&” e “||” e “and” e “or” em PHP? Qual usar?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A avaliação de curto circuito é algo implementado pelos compiladores/interpretadores para economizar recursos e acelerar a avaliação de condições. Em um teste condicional composto, se a primeira condição pode garantir a execução ou não do bloco.

Por exemplo:

- com a variável `$a`, como a primeira condição já está `false` e o operador é um `&&` (E): **falso E qualquer coisa** vai sempre dar **falso**;
- com a variável `$b`, a primeira condição é `true` e o operador é um `||` (OU): **verdadeiro OU qualquer coisa** vai sempre dar **verdadeiro**;
- os exemplos `$c` e `$d` seguem a mesma ideia, respectivamente.

O link citado pelo @rray sobre precedência de operadores é bem válido!

Acrescento a explicação sobre a tabela verdade de cada operador [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_verdade).

E também o link específico sobre curto-circuito, encontrado [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito).

Comment: Muito boa explicação, como eu poderia está usando esse conceito para c#?