# Como fazer uma IF ler dois tipos de categoria ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php

Boa noite, bem, desejo saber como posso colocar: `if ($this->GetCategoryName() == 'mmorpg' OR 'shots')` na mesma linha de código, sem precisar fazer isso:

```
if ($this->GetCategoryName() == 'mmorpg') {
    if ($this->GetCategoryName() == 'shots') {
        $url = $c_url;
    } else {
        $url = $c_url;
    }
} else {
    $url = U_LANG.'/'.$url_cat;
}
```

Comment: `if ($this->GetCategoryName() == 'mmorpg' && $this->GetCategoryName() == 'shots') {`

Comment: kkk eae man :D, se tem conta Discord? Sou novo em PHP, ai se poderia ser meu professor rs, ajeitei já o if, era só por o `OR` assim: `or` ai funcionou: `$this->GetCategoryName() == 'mmorpg' or 'shots'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim:

```
if ($this->GetCategoryName() == 'mmorpg' && $this->GetCategoryName() == 'shots') {
```

Mas tem um erro de lógica, se é uma coisa não é outra.

Em PHP você pode usar

- `&&` para AND
- `||` para OR, será que não é isso que busca?

Mas talvez te interesse mais fazer assim:

```
$cat = $this->GetCategoryName();
$url = ($cat == 'mmorpg' || $cat == 'shots') ? 'url1' : 'url2';
```

Ou seja "se a categoria for mmorpg OU categoria for shots, é url1, senão url2"

Note que PHP tem `and` e `or` também, mas muda a precedência, veja aqui:

> [Qual a diferença entre "&&" e "||" e "and" e "or" em PHP? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47886/70)

Comment: Sim, esse 2º método ficou melhor: `$url = ($this->GetCategoryName() == 'mmorpg' || $this->GetCategoryName() == 'shots') ? $c_url : U_LANG.'/'.$url_cat;` obrigado rs

Comment: `Note que PHP tem and e or também, mas muda a precedência.` Sim, realmente.