# Como fazer um if com um valor maior e outro menor?

Tags: php, if, operadores

Queria saber se é possível fazer um `if` ou um `for` em PHP da seguinte forma:

```
$valor = 7
if ( $valor se o valor for maior que > 5 menor que < 10) {
  //... Comando a ser executado ... 
}else if (se o valor foi maior que > 10 é menor que < 15){
  //... Comando a ser executado 
}else {
 // idade inferior a 5 anos 
 }
```

Comment: Sim, é possível. Já estudou os operadores do PHP?

Comment: bem simples if ($valor > 5 && $valor < 10), mas isso é o basico recomendo estudar o basico.

Comment: Nossa,coisa tão simples  eu pensei em fazer isso..Mas  não fiz, brigadao mano kkk

Comment: Talvez você não conheça mas o `PHP` possui uma documentação oficial bem completa. Por exemplo a explicação do funcionamento da condição `if`:http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O primeiro passo é definir bem qual é o seu problema. Mesmo em português ele não está bem definido. Uma coisa é `for`, outra é um `if`, outra é um `if` e depois `else if`, e mesmo que isso seja menos relevante, o fator de descrever o operador por extenso e usá-lo simbolicamente torna o texto ainda mais confuso, inclusive porque o texto não está bem ligado, e ligação é a chave para a solução que deseja. Eu acho até que entendi o que quer, mas como está confuso pode ser que meu entendimento esteja errado. Vou tentar responder o que entendi baseando no comentário.

Seria isto:

```
if ($valor > 5 && $valor < 10) {
    //... Comando a ser executado ... 
} else if ($valor > 10 && $valor < 15) {
    //... Comando a ser executado 
} else {
    // idade inferior a 5 anos 
}
```

Usei o [operador de `&&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101) ([em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/101)) para concatenar duas condições relacionais de forma que ambas devem ser verdadeiras para entrar no bloco.

Mas tem alguns problemas neste código.

Se a idade for 10 ele vai dizer que a idade é menor que 5. Se a idade for maior ou igual a 15 ele vai dizer que é menor que 5. Então o correto seria algo assim (eu tive que interpretar o que eu acho correto, porque mesmo em português não dá para saber qual é o requisito, não sei qual é a fórmula correta a ser aplicada.

```
if ($valor >= 15) {
    //... trata para idade maior ou igual a 15 ... 
} else if ($valor >= 10 && $valor < 15) {
    //... trata para idade entre 10 e 14 anos ...
} else if ($valor >= 5 && $valor < 10) {
    //... trata para idade entre 5 e 9 anos ...
} else {
    // ... trata para idade inferior a 5 anos ...
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ConditionConcatanation.php).

Antes de mais nada programar é entender o problema e achar uma solução adequada. Codificar é um detalhe bobo que temos que fazer. Aprender sintaxe não é aprender programar.